# Asp.NET check if CustomValidator is valid clientside after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `CustomValidator` that checks some stuff on postback--it can't do it clientside.

All of my validators are hidden because the styles are ugly, and in the uncommon case this particular validator fails, I want to trigger a nice bootstrap popover when the page reloads.

At the moment, the page just reloads with no indication as to why it didn't go onto the next step of the wizard.

What's the best way I can detect whether the validator succeeded or failed after the page loads?

I'm considering just using a `HiddenField` and if the validator is invalid, setting the value.  That seems like a workaround for something that should already exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can add errors to the `System.Web.Mvc.ModelState`

```
 public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
 {
     if(validation test fails){
         ModelState.AddModelError("key","My custom validation failed!");
         //where key is a property of the model
         return View(); //a @Html.ValidationSummary() in your view will display the error message for you
     }

     if(ModelState.IsValid){ //this if condition is not required since I return on error in my example but just in case you need for your code it will not be valid since you called ModelState.AddModelError
         //validation passed
         //do more work
     }

     //and just in case you needed to manually flush the ModelState of your custom validation
     ModelState["key"].Errors.Clear();
  }
```

Then in your view:

```
   @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#modalCustomErrorId').modal('show');
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: I'm using Asp.NET WebForms... my limited understanding is that I can't combine that with Mvc.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are correct, in a sense, you can do Web Forms and MVC in the same project but you cannot use MVC type validation for a .aspx. So no you cannot use the solution I provided you